# Have a batch file minimize all windows but itself OR activate something that can

Tags: windows-7, batch

Hello i am trying to have a batch file that minimizes all other windows other than itself. also if possible have it be selected so you can type into it.

TLDR: make batchfile only thing on screen

P.s: vbscrips won't work to send windows key + Home it doesn't support winkey and even if it did it wouldn't work if some thing else was selected

Comment: A batchfile can't do this.

Comment: Well can it activate something else that can?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no windows command that can do this, so it would require specific 3rd-party software, which is off-topic here on SuperUser. You may have some luck with an Auto-It, auto hotkey or similar scripting language.

Comment: Would you be OK with launching a new window instead of restoring the original?

Comment: LPChip: well there is powershell but I am not familiar with it

Comment: Ben N: Sure I can just put the rest of the code in the second

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you said you're OK with launching a second batch file in the new window, you can easily accomplish this with no third-party software - you can use PowerShell!

This command minimizes all windows:

```
(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).MinimizeAll()
```

And this executes the second batch file (e.g. `myfile.bat`) in a new maximized window:

```
Start-Process myfile.bat -WindowStyle Maximized
```

You can run those two PowerShell commands with this batch command (I've golfed them a bit for faster typing):

```
powershell -command "(new-object -com shell.application).minimizeall();start myfile.bat -window Maximized"
```

Comment: I minimizes but throws a error and doesn't start the file.

Comment: The error to too long for a comment so here's a link: https://imgur.com/a/eCPnl

Comment: @Pizza Ah, my mistake; my shortening technique apparently was introduced in a later version of PowerShell than the one that ships with Windows 7. Answer updated. Try it now?

Answer (score 2):

#### I am trying to have a batch file that minimizes all other windows other than itself

You can use [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) from [nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) to do this.

Command line:

```
nircmd sendkeypress rwin+home
```

Batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
nircmd sendkeypress rwin+home
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Put `nircmd` somewhere in your `PATH` or use the full name in the batch file.

---

#### NirCmd Command Reference - sendkeypress

> ```
>  sendkeypress [Keys Combination 1] [Keys Combination 2] [Keys Combination 3] ...
> ```
>
> Sends one or more key press combinations to the system. The operating
>   system will behave exactly as the user really pressed the specified
>   keys combination.
>
> The [Key Combination] parameter specifies a single key press to send
>   or a combination of a single key and shift/ctrl/alt/Windows keys,
>   delimited by '+' character.
>
> The key in the [Key Combination] parameter can be specifed as numeric
>   virtual key code (For example: 0x2e for Delete key), or as one of the
>   following predefined values: a - z and 0 - 9 (for alphanumeric keys),
>   F1 - F24 (for Fxx keys), shift, ctrl, alt, enter, esc ,leftshift,
>   rightshift, leftctrl, rightctrl, leftmenu, rightmenu, spc (space),
>   down, up, left, right, home, end, insert, delete, plus, comma, minus,
>   period, lwin, rwin (Windows key), apps, pageup, pagedown, tab,
>   multiply, add, subtract, separator, divide, backspace, pause,
>   capslock, numlock, scroll, printscreen.

Source [NirCmd Command Reference - sendkeypress](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/sendkeypress.html)

---

#### What is nircmd?

> NirCmd is a small command-line utility that allows you to do some useful tasks without displaying any user interface. By running NirCmd with simple command-line option, you can write and delete values and keys in the Registry, write values into INI file, dial to your internet account or connect to a VPN network, restart windows or shut down the computer, create shortcut to a file, change the created/modified date of a file, change your display settings, turn off your monitor, open the door of your CD-ROM drive, and more...

Source [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Comment: Thank your for your input its neater than the other solution but has a slight problem I have it so that this runs on unlock so is I have google chrome selected It minimizes everything but chrome. :-)

Comment: @Pizza Try calling `nircmd win activate title "Command Prompt"` before the `nircmd sendkeypress ...`

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, no other ideas ...