# How to make a batch file a task switcher?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

How to make a batch file a task switcher?

With windows XP and Windows 7 batch files...
The batch file is:

```
cls  
@echo off  
echo 1  
start /normal c:\windows\system32\taskmgr.exe  
echo 2  
pause
```

The problem is the focus stays on Task Manager.
The problem is the focus is not on the batch window.

How to get the focus back on to the batch file window?
How to switch tasks to batch?

How to get the focus on the batch window by using batch file commands and without using the mouse to click on the batch file window and without pressing Alt-Tab on the keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

#### Start the program minimized

To prevent a program started from a batch file (or the Command Prompt) from taking the focus, start it minimized:

```
start /min /normal c:\windows\system32\taskmgr.exe
```

This opens the program, but because the window is minimized, it cannot take the focus.

---

**EDIT:** Starting Task Manager is a special case. Regardless of how you start this program, it *always* takes the system focus.

In this case, there's nothing you can do.  It's simply not possible to reclaim the system focus from a batch file.  (Remember, batch scripting comes from the days when there were no application windows at all!)

Comment: Only half works because Task Manager is Min, but focus is not on the batch window.    start /min /normal c:\windows\system32\taskmgr.exe

Comment: You are correct...that's interesting. It seems no matter how you start Task Manager, it takes over the focus.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Great we can both duplicate the Problem.  For clarity the focus needs to be always on the batch window to do Ctrl-C to stop batch.

Comment: @Joseph As explained in my answer, you can't return the focus to the batch window once it gets moved elsewhere (unless you're open to using non-batch programs).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a *unique time stamp variable* in the batch script and use that variable to set as the value of its [title](https://ss64.com/nt/title.html) per each execution of the script.

You can then use [appactivate](https://ss64.com/vb/appactivate.html) passing it the value of the cmd window [title](https://ss64.com/nt/title.html) to activate, create a dynamic VBScript with the value, and then execute that script with [cscript](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html) to activate it.

I just used `ping -n 06 127.0.0.1 > nul` as a 5 second pause to wait from after the time **Task Manager** is launched before the actual batch script titled window is activated by [cscript](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html) execution.

### Batch Script

```
cls 

SET t=%~n0_%date:~10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%
SET t=%t: =0%
TITLE %t%

@echo off  
echo 1  
start /normal c:\windows\system32\taskmgr.exe  
echo 2  

:VBSDynamicBuild
SET TempVBSFile=%temp%\~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO objShell.AppActivate "%t%"                   >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ping -n 06 127.0.0.1 > nul
CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"

pause
```

---

### Further Resources

- [title](https://ss64.com/nt/title.html)
- [appactivate](https://ss64.com/vb/appactivate.html)
- [cscript](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
cls
@echo off

echo 1
start /normal c:\windows\system32\taskmgr.exe

REM Wait for Task Manager to open
    CALL :Wait 1

REM Alt+Tab back to cmd window
    CALL :AltTab

echo 2
pause

GOTO :eof



REM Subroutines:
:wait
    @CHOICE /D Y /T:%1% > NUL
    EXIT /B

:AltTab
    (
        ECHO.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^).SendKeys "%%{TAB}"
    )>%tmp%\tmp.vbs
    CALL %tmp%\tmp.vbs
    DEL %tmp%\tmp.vbs
    EXIT /B
```

This will:

- Echo 1
- Open Task Manager
- Wait for Task Manager to start (1s)
- Create, run and delete a VBS-script to Alt+Tab back to cmd-window
- Echo 2
- Pause

Comment: @Facebook you need 10k rep to see deleted posts.

Answer (score 0):

In a batch file, this has done the trick, tested a few times ok.
Restarted computer and still tested ok.

**C:\WINDOWS\nircmd.exe sendkeypress rwin+home**

NirCmd v2.81 (Console Version)
http://www.nirsoft.net

Above batch command changes the system focus
from "Windows Task Manager"
and puts the system focus
to the Batch file window.

Background:
Ran batch that
calls taskmgr.exe and
batch does above command and
now pressing Ctrl-C stops batch.

No need to mouse click on batch window.
No need to Alt-Tab over to the batch window.

The above, one line, batch file command changes system focus.

Disadvantage nircmd.exe is third party software
versus out of the box solution.

Reference
[Have a batch file minimize all windows but itself OR activate something that can](https://superuser.com/questions/1178736/have-a-batch-file-minimize-all-windows-but-itself-or-activate-something-that-can)

--